# new component generating problem - Angular

Tags: angular, npm

I'm running this `npm` command to generate a new component

```
ng g c servers
```

I got the following errors:

```
core_1.PriorityQueue is not a constructor TypeError: core_1.PriorityQueue is not a constructor
at new TaskScheduler (/Users/almashrgy/Documents/Development/second-app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/task.js:20:23)
at SchematicEngine.createContext (/Users/almashrgy/Documents/Development/second-app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/engine.js:81:31)
at SchematicImpl.call (/Users/almashrgy/Documents/Development/second-app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/schematic.js:35:38)
at Promise (/Users/almashrgy/Documents/Development/second-app/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/schematic-run.js:73:23)
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at Class.run (/Users/almashrgy/Documents/Development/second-app/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/schematic-run.js:72:16)
at Class.run (/Users/almashrgy/Documents/Development/second-app/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/generate.js:161:33)
at resolve (/Users/almashrgy/Documents/Development/second-app/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js:261:20)
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at Class.validateAndRun (/Users/almashrgy/Documents/Development/second-app/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js:240:12)
Mohameds-MacBook-Pro:second-app almashrgy$
```

Comment: What version of angular-cli are you using? Could you please add the output of `ng --version` to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Check this link. Here is the same issue has been told to resolve by using devkit-core in version 0.0.29 to devDependencies.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9374

[a link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9374)